# jQuery: create overlay or lightbox effect around existing div

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui

Is there a jQuery plugin or effect that will create an overlay/lightbox effect around an existing div element? In essence, I'd like to darken the entire page except for a particular div that's already in the DOM.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a premade one: http://dev7studios.com/demo/jquery-spotlight/

And here's a tutorial on how to roll your own: http://web.enavu.com/tutorials/making-a-cool-spotlight-effect-with-jquery/

Comment: Simple, and does exactly what I needed.